# Design pattern for token class

Tags: java, enums

My program contains the following classes

```
class Token {
    ptivate TokenType t;
    // ...
    public Token(TokenType t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    // ...
    public TokenType getType() {return t}
}

interface TokenType {}

enum Function implements TokenType {
    // ...
    LOG {
        double apply(double x) {
            return Math.log(x);
        }
    }
    // ... 
    abstract double apply(double x);
}

enum Operation implements TokenType {
    // ... 
    abstract double apply(double x, double y);
}

enum Const implements TokenType {
    // no behaviors
}
```

Now when I want to use them I have to do

```
Token t = new Token(Function.LOG);
Function f = (Function) t.getType();
double x = f.apply(1.0);
```

I need a list of tokens with different token types. Is it a bad idea to have different enum classes with different behaviors that all implement an empty interface? How can I avoid downcasting here?

Answer (score 2):

Make `Token` generic:

```
class Token<T extends Enum<T> & TokenType> {
    ptivate T t;
    // ...
    public Token(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    // ...
    public T getType() {return t}
}
```

Of course, if you don't actually need the enum constraint, you could simplify the type variable bound to:

```
<T extends TypeToken>
```

Then:

```
Token<Function> t = new Token<>(Function.LOG);
Function f = t.getType();
double x = f.apply(1.0);
```

---

From the comments, it seems that you are concerned about how to design to have a heterogeneous list of `TokenType` items.

The problem you've got here is that the `apply` methods aren't part of an interface common to the different implementations of `TokenType` (such as `TokenType` itself). Given a list of such instances, you currently have to check what the type of the instance is, cast, and then invoke the appropriate method.

Instead, consider how you might have a common method. You are taking some number of doubles; and returning a double. One way to implement this is with a stack, e.g.

```
interface DoubleStack {
  double pop();
  void push(double d);
}

interface TokenType {
  void apply(DoubleStack stack);
}
```

Now you can implement the apply methods for log where it pops once and pushes once; or operation, where it pops twice and pushes once.

Then you don't need to worry about the type: you can simply invoke the apply methods on any instance:

```
DoubleStack stack = ...;
for (TokenType t : listOfTokenTypes) {
  t.apply(stack);
}
```

Comment: Can a generic class be used with a list of tokens?

Comment: @Dante `List<Token<Foo>>`

Comment: Yes: if they are of homogeneous type, you can use a `List<Token<Function>>`; if they are of different types, you can use a `List<Token<?>>`. Of course, you've then got the problem of how to invoke the `apply` method... But you've got that with your current approach too.

Comment: Unfortunately they are NOT of homogeneous type.

Comment: @Dante by the way, if you were interested in how to do this for a heterogeneous list of instances, you should have stated that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as whether it is bad practice? Yes it is. The entire point of Java enums is that it is a defined, easy to lookup list of instances that cannot be altered programattically. It is supposed to be impossible to instantiate non-hardcoded instances of an enum class. Can non-enum classes also implement the `TokenType` interface? To have multiple enum classes that all implement a certain interface and then write methods that can take from any of those enum classes, or indeed any class that implements the interface, defeats the purpose of using an enum.